# OpenVpn doesn't connect via TCP

Tags: openvpn, tcp, udp

I created a OpenVpn server with TCP but client can't connect and receive this error

> Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...

But UDP works perfectly.

This is config of server:

```
local a.b.c.d
port 8889
proto tcp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
server-ipv6 x:1194:1194:1194::/64
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

and this is config of client:

```
setenv UV_ID a1b1c72e424746b4878b287f80ec92a9
setenv UV_NAME autumn-forest-5919
client
dev tun
dev-type tun
remote x.x.x.x 8889 tcp-client
nobind
persist-tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
verb 2
mute 3
push-peer-info
ping 10
ping-restart 60
hand-window 70
server-poll-timeout 4
reneg-sec 2592000
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo no
auth-user-pass
key-direction 1
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
X
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
X
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
X
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

This is error I get while trying to connect to OpenVpn with TCP:

```
[thawing-skies-7547] TCP connection established with [AF_INET6]::ffff:x.x.x.x:15112 
[thawing-skies-7547] Sun Sep 25 14:35:20 2022 x.x.x.xTLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity) 
[thawing-skies-7547] Sun Sep 25 14:35:20 2022 x.x.x.xTLS Error: TLS handshake failed 
[thawing-skies-7547] Sun Sep 25 14:35:20 2022 x.x.x.xFatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
```

I mention that I removed the IPv6 from server and still got this error!

```
[autumn-meadow-1825] Sun Sep 25 18:34:14 2022 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:13731
[autumn-meadow-1825] Sun Sep 25 18:34:24 2022 x.x.x.x:13506 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
[autumn-meadow-1825] Sun Sep 25 18:34:24 2022 x.x.x.x:13506 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
[autumn-meadow-1825] Sun Sep 25 18:34:24 2022 x.x.x.x:13506 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
```

I installed pritunl and set port as 8889 but still TCP try to connect to other ports!

I want to forward OpenVpn ports from another VPS and UDP ports can't be forward so I have to use TCP.

any solution?

**==========UPDATE============**

I changed /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf with normal openvpn server:

```
local x.x.x.x
port 8889
proto tcp-server
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "block-outside-dns"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

and still same error

Normal openvpn client.ovpn:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote x.x.x.x 8889
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
X
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
X
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
X
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

openvpn --version

```
OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018, LZO 2.08
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_sysroot=no
```

**==========UPDATE============**

I think there is a problem with tls in windows or my ISP network because I test with a VPS and it connected successfully but with my desktop I cant connect.How can I disable TLS in openvpn?

Comment: "_UDP ports can't be forward[ed]_" - yes they can. Perhaps your platform can't forward them, but you didn't specify what platform (OS) you're using

Comment: @roaima Both servers OS is Ubuntu 18.04, I can change their OS if it is necessary.

Comment: @roaima and about config,that is general config of OpenVpn, and I think proto tcp defined it

Comment: @roaima I edited my ask

Comment: What version of openvpn are you using (2.3, 2.4, or something else)?

Comment: @roaima I changed my config and still same! I edited my ask.OpenVPN 2.4.4

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/GettingStartedwithOVPN) provides an example for TCP:

> Using UDP requires just to add
>
> ```
>  proto udp
> ```
>
> in both client and server configurations. For TCP, the server requires
>
> ```
> proto tcp-server
> ```
>
> and the client requires
>
> ```
> proto tcp-client
> ```

Basically, TCP connections are directional whereas UDP ones are not. Your phrase `proto tcp` should have raised an error - it's always worth checking for errors when changing a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First, is the TCP connection between client and server fine? You can test it by simply telneting to the server (make sure the OpenVPN server is running).

If it doesn't connect, it's not an OpenVPN issue. You should check your firewall etc. Port 8080 is sometimes used by HTTP services and can be blocked by firewalls or intercepted by transparent HTTP proxies. If you're having TCP connection issues on port 8080, try a different port, such as port 1194/tcp, which is reserved by IANA for OpenVPN.

Regards,
James